# Do we need the [error-management] tag?

Tags: discussion

I just ran into a question with the [error-management] tag. Presently, there are only 7 [questions that use it](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-management), all with low to no votes & all seem to apply it as a stand in for "I have an error/bug".

To my mind [error-management] means things like bug tracking, dealing with regression errors & logging crashes. Of those, only logging is here discussed with much frequency.

For comparison, Stack Overflow has a tag for bug-tracking, but not error management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the tag from questions where it is misused.

Using it as "I have an error/bug" is not particularly descriptive & already covered by debugging.

If actual error-management related questions do come in & use it fine. If not, it will eventually age out.

Right now it's limited to a small number of questions, so the workload & question churn is minimal.

Comment: For the record, I'm still open to other solutions. In the meantime, lacking superior alternatives, I'm going to mark this as accepted.